# Button click circle unbound ripple anim

Tags: android

**I have find out the solution, just simply
 set the back ground to `RippleDrawable`.**

Normally when click on a default style button will appears this effect [spuare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iTlw.jpg) but how can i make a button on click animation llike this [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIPJc.jpg) and is there any good suggestion of any other button click animation,

```
<ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"/>
```

And my java code

```
startbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is your code? This is likely to be downvoted for its poor quality http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thx for replying any way , code is comming

Comment: you might want to remove that final line - it is not cute and is a downvote magnet